# Angular App With No Constant Address Bar Value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am working on a project which the deadline is really soon. Add showing the routed url's  in the url bar will create so many security issues for me. What i am trying to do is this:

Is there a way that I can use routing in the app internally but not show it to the user the url in the address bar?

Exmple:

```
when('/grid/:param1/:param2', {    
     templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/grid/views/gridMainView.html',
     controller: 'gridController'
}).

http://foodForMe.com
```

I will be able to use the     http://foodForMe.com/#/grid/11/22 but the user will just see     http://foodForMe.com in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.history.pushState` in your controller to change the url that is visible **but that is not solving your security problem. Security thought obscurity is not security.**

`window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);`

Answer (score 0):

Use  **ui-router**

> Unlike the $route service in the Angular ngRoute module, which is
>   organized around URL routes, UI-Router is organized around states,
>   which may optionally have routesched.

- Link  : [ui-route](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)
- Guide : [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)